# INPlayMediaIntent ignores terms like 'music' and 'radio'

Tags: ios, sirikit, intents-extension

I'm working on a media app, and I'd like to improve its Siri interactions.  I've implemented an Intents extension, with "radio" as the media category, and I'm refining the `resolveMediaItems` method.  Typically if I tell Siri `Play <search query> in <my app>`, and then examine the `INPlayMediaIntent` in the debugger, I see something like this

```
<INPlayMediaIntent: 0x143f181c0> {
    playShuffled = 0;
    mediaSearch = <INMediaSearch: 0x143d19b50> {
        reference = 0;
        mediaType = 18;
        sortOrder = 0;
        albumName = <null>;
        mediaName = search query;
        genreNames = (
        );
        artistName = <null>;
        moodNames = (
        );
        releaseDate = <null>;
        mediaIdentifier = <null>;
    };
    mediaContainer = <null>;
    playbackRepeatMode = none;
    mediaItems = <null>;
    resumePlayback = 0;
    playbackQueueLocation = now;
    playbackSpeed = <null>;
}
```

where the `mediaSearch.mediaName` has the data from the speaker that I can use to resolve the query.

Unfortunately, if the query contains the words 'music' or 'radio' these will not be included in the `mediaName` field.  If the query contains just these words, e.g.,  `"Play music in <my app>"`, the field will be `<null>` and the `INPlayMediaIntent` will effectively contain no content whatsoever.

Given the content that app provides, knowing whether the terms 'music' and 'radio' were used are absolutely necessary for sensibly resolving the query.  Can anyone provide guidance on how I can get these terms to be visible within the `INPlayMediaIntent` object?

Answer (score 0):

The words 'music' and 'radio' seem to *almost* never appear in the `mediaName` field, but their presence in the Siri query is usually reflected in the `mediaType` field.  This looks like a Int but actually corresponds to the `INMediaItemType` enum listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inmediasearch/3074251-mediatype). It seems that the two values I was seeing (16 and 18) correspond to `.radioStation` and `.music` respectively (why `.music` and not `.musicStation`, I don't know).

Mostly, between the `mediaType` and `mediaName` I was able to code meaningful ways to resolve most queries.

Still some queries  were intractable.  "music radio" gets the `mediaType`  `.radioStation` and an empty field for `mediaName` and so the query passed to my IntentsExtention has no way of knowing the user asked for music.